# Two TTL pulses mutiplexed on one wire

Tags: analog, ttl

I am looking for a way to convert two TTL pulses from two MCU outputs, to one wire (referenced to common ground on both ends), over a long length of cable. I would like to do this with as little latency as possible, so a digital format may not be ideal, I was hoping to find a way to do this using just analog components.

My initial thought was to boost Output 1 to +15V, and to invert and boost Output 2 to -15V, sending both over the same wire, then find a way to strip them at the other end of the cable and level shift back to TTL. Output 1 and Output 2 will never occur at the same time.

Comment: How long is the cable?

Comment: Between 600-1200 meters

Comment: That's one of those things you should have mentioned before. It kind of changes everything.

Answer (score 1):

Bias the line to VDD/2. Have one digital pulse pull high. Have the other digital pulse pull low. To data-recover, have 2 comparators, one tripping at VDD/4 and the other tripping at VDD * 3/4.

Consider using TriState drivers to pull up or pull down or FLOAT.

Comment: What will happen if pulses occur at the same time?

Comment: @JakubRakus: Nothing! (But OP says this will never happen.)

Comment: It's up to 1200 meters in length, we now find out! The difference  in ground voltage alone could be ... well, a lot. I've seen a situation where the ground voltage between two buildings just 100 meters away was 7 kV. (It was a weird situation. But I've seen it. Had to switch to fiber optic cable to resolve the communications issue, there.)

Comment: I was able to do a single pulse using a set of MAX232 chips that were pre-existing, but I think the cable was more like 300 meters, this was a while ago. The ground difference is not much, certainly not 7kV, but I don't have a figure handy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation of your proposed idea of using positive pulses to represent one data line and negative pulses to represent the other.  In this approach, each input pulse generates a pulse pair, consisting of a positive pulse and corresponding negative pulse, both of equal amplitude and time.

I'll refer to these inputs as A and B.  When A occurs, the output is a positive leading edge pulse cycle.  B produces a negative leading edge cycle.

[image]

The advantage this offers is the zero baseline does not shift.  Each transmitted pulse pair has a net voltage of zero taken over its complete cycle.  Without baseline compensation of some sort, more positive than negative pulses over time will charge the capacitance in your cable to create a positive baseline shift.  Conversely, more negative pulses will cause a negative baseline shift at the receiving end.  The baseline shift can be a challenge when you're doing amplitude discrimination at the receiving end.

If this is more complexity than what you need, then you might consider converting your two inputs to positive and negative current pulses through a bipolar current source.